# How to load a controller class from admin to controller class in catalog

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

How to load a controller class from admin to controller class in catalog

/admin/controller/tool/getip.php

load function ip() from getip.php in: /catalog/controller/account/account.php

getip.php

```
class ControllerGetIp extends Controller {

public function ip() {

return ...;

}
...
}
```

account.php

```
class ControllerAccount extends Controller {

public function index() {

load ip();
..

}
```

Comment: This is not so easy, because you will need login to admin first to access that class. the simplest way to copy that class to your catalog controller file and if you need access to DB copy corresponding model class to catalog model file.

Answer (score -1):

Try to write the code below in your account controller

```php
$ip = $this->load->controller('tool/getip');
$getip = $ip->ip();
```

Comment: The question is to call a Catalog controller function from Admin controller function. Learn to read before teaching.